# The placeholder appears with display issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I am using select2 V4.0.8 in my Angular 8 project; the problem in that when the user types a value into the field then remove,the placeholder appears with display issue:
[image]

Moreover i want the field don't show Searching..

[image]

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to the latest version.
And I would recommend adjusting this with CSS to match your theme. This is a CSS issue.